# ajax php variables in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the below code, which was previously working fine:

```
var xmlHttp
var layername
var url
function update(layer, url) {
    var xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject(); //you have this defined elsewhere

    if(xmlHttp==null) {
        alert("Your browser is not supported?");
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete") {
            document.getElementById(layer).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        } else if (xmlHttp.readyState==1 || xmlHttp.readyState=="loading") {
            document.getElementById(layer).innerHTML="loading";
        }

       //etc
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}


function updateByPk(layer, pk) {
   url = "get_auction.php?cmd=GetAuctionData&pk="+pk+"&sid="+Math.random();
   update(layer, url);
}


function updateByQuery(layer, query) {
   url = "get_records.php?cmd=GetRecordSet&query="+query+"&sid="+Math.random();
   update(layer, url);
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e)
    {

        try
        {
                xmlHttp =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}

    }
return xmlHttp;
}
function makewindows(){
child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
var phpstring = <?php $out = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row2['ARTICLE_DESC']), ENT_QUOTES); echo("'$out'"); ?>; 
child1.document.write(phpstring); 
//child1.document.write("<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row2['ARTICLE_DESC']), ENT_QUOTES); ?>");
child1.document.close(); 
}
```

The part that is commeneted out was working fine in a previus version, in that javascript was replacing row2['ARTICLE_DESC'], a php variable with the contents of the variable. This javascript file is included from a script tag in a php file, and always worked fine. I have changed something recently however, I am not sure what the specific thing was, butnow I get these errors, from firebug:

```
function makewindows(){
    child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
    child1.document.write("<br />
    <b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: row2 in <b>C:\Programme\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\records4\fetchlayers.js</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
    null");
    child1.document.close();
    }
```

unterminated string literal on line 57 and the updateByQuery is not defined.

I have no idea why I get either of those errors, and why updateByPk does not throw an error. I am even more confused as to what article_Desc is being expanded to and how. This happens on the index.php, which has a link to call updateByQuery, which would load a section via ajax which would have a link to updateByPk, which would display the final section, which would have a link to makewindows(), where article_Desc would relate to the relevant $pk

This was all working fine, and I can not find out why it no longer is.

would it help if I were to paste the php files somewhere?

edit.

i do not understand why this is happening, but have tried to modified the function so it takes a paramter.

```
function makewindows(html){
child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
child1.document.write(html);
child1.document.close(); 
}
```

in conjunction with thse two snippets of php

```
$html = json_encode(htmlspecialchars($row2['ARTICLE_DESC']));
```

and

```
<a href='#' onclick='makewindows(/"".$html."/"); return false;'>Click for full description </a></p>
```

Comment: If you think my answer is right, please validate it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything indicates the problem is in your PHP file. The notice you are getting is from PHP and not from JavaScript as you may be assuming.

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: row2 in <b>C:\Programme\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\records4\fetchlayers.js</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
    null");
```

So the problem is in here:

```
<?php $out = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row2['ARTICLE_DESC']), ENT_QUOTES); echo("'$out'"); ?>;
```

The **$row2** array is not defined, so **$row2['ARTICLE_DESC']** doesn't exist. You should verify from where it should come from because I couldn't find it in the code you provided.